# How to edit the subject of an email I received in mutt's mailbox list?

Tags: mutt

Everything is in my title. I received an header with a huge typos that I want to keep in my mailbox for a while, but it is really unpleasant to read this mistake over and over. So I would like to edit it. Command "e" lets me edit the body of the email, not the subject. So of course I am not interested in the "s" (edit-subject) command used in compose mode.

Comment: You could forward the mail to yourself with a new subject and delete/archive the original.

Comment: thanks, but not really what I was asking for

Comment: could someone explain the downvote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the `<edit>` command, bound to <kbd>e</kbd> lets you edit the complete raw message, including all headers.

From the documentation:

```
<edit> (default: e)

    This command (available in the index and pager) allows you to edit the raw
    current message as it's present in the mail folder. After you have finished
    editing, the changed message will be appended to the current folder, and
    the original message will be marked for deletion; if the message is
    unchanged it won't be replaced.
```

I tried unsetting `edit_hdrs` and all headers are still there for editing.

Comment: Nice ! I tried this of course but for some reason I could not find the title.

Comment: The problem I have with this solution is that it modifies send-time of the message. Do you know any way around that?